# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 when running a flutter app

Tags: java, flutter, exception, connection-timeout

when running a flutter project following error comes and running fails

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:590)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:588)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:587)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:631)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:202)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1263)     
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)      
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)   
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)    
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             45.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried changing java version of my computer and I checked the connection but none of them works..

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Please make sure that your internet connection is working and if possible, use a different network to test it out.

Comment: @NaqeebAbid yes i checked using different networks but not works same error

Comment: it was a connection problem..i was able to fix the problem by changing the network thank @NaqeebAbid for answering